# One Sub for multiple VBA Userform Items

Tags: vba, function, listbox

I am writing a program in VBA where I use multiple listboxes in a Userform. Is it possible to write one program for more than one listbox (a single program to control Private Sub Listbox1_Click, Private Sub Listbox2_Click, and Private Sub Listbox4_Click)

Thanks

Comment: You cannot make one Sub to handle all ListBox events, but you can make them (Event Procedures) to call the same Sub, passing any parameters ByRef, probably passing itself as well if you want to distinguish them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class to handle the Listbox Events and use a class level array or collection to hold references to the Listboxes.
[image]

### ListboxEventsClass Code

```
Public WithEvents lBox As MSForms.ListBox

Private Sub lBox_Click()
    MsgBox "You clicked: " & lBox.Name _
    & vbCrLf & "Value: " & lBox.Value
End Sub
```

### Userform Code

```
Private lBoxes(3) As ListboxEventsClass

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set lBoxes(0) = New ListboxEventsClass
    Set lBoxes(1) = New ListboxEventsClass
    Set lBoxes(2) = New ListboxEventsClass

    Set lBoxes(0).lBox = ListBox1
    Set lBoxes(1).lBox = ListBox2
    Set lBoxes(2).lBox = ListBox3

    ListBox1.List = Array("Red", "White", "Blue")
    ListBox2.List = Array("Dog", "Cat", "Horse")
    ListBox3.List = Array("VBA", "Java", "C++")
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! So we can add all other Events this way by using a Class module? In theory, we can do the same for ComboBox and TextBoxes too?

Comment: Yes, you can use it for any type of control.  You should read [Events and Event Procedures in the VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/events.aspx) on Chip Pearson's Website.  It will give you a good overview on Event handling.